# How to traverse the tree to get all combinations of the leaf node?

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, combinations

I have a tree like the below and I want to get all combinations of the leaf node in the penultimate layer:

[image]

```
[E,C,H]
[E,C,I]
[E,C,J]
[E,C,K]
[F,C,H]
[F,C,I]
[F,C,J]
[F,C,K]
```

I want to use a function like [product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to implement this traverse.

The code to create the tree:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, name, parent=None):
        self.name = name
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = []

    def add(self, child):
        self.children.append(child)


    def showDetails(self, depth=1):
        print(self.name)
        for child in self.children:
            print("\t"*depth, end="")
            child.showDetails(depth+1)

a = Node('A')
b = Node('B', a)
c = Node('C', a)
d = Node('D', a)
a.add(b)
a.add(c)
a.add(d)

e = Node('E', b)
f = Node('F', b)
b.add(e)
b.add(f)

g = Node('G', d)
d.add(g)

h = Node('H', g)
i = Node('I', g)
j = Node('J', g)
k = Node('K', g)
g.add(h)
g.add(i)
g.add(j)
g.add(k)

a.showDetails()
```

Comment: Due to the code limitation in the question content, I put the code to create the tree [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73511242/7394312).

Comment: I don’t see why you could not put the code used to create the tree in question ? BTW , to which level would you go up in your tree to search for other leafs that could fit ?

Comment: Is this a homework ?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you facing an issue?

Comment: Hi @PtitXav thanks for your reply,   It is not homework, is a sub-problem in my personal project. I want to search for the penultimate layer.

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Hi, to be honest, I have no idea to do it correctly.

Comment: I still do not understand why you talk about penultimate : do you mean find all penultimate nodes and find all combinations that can be done with  one leaf from each of these nodes ?

Comment: "penultimate" doesn't mean what you think it means. If you want leaf nodes, then say "leaf nodes." The "penultimate layer" is the next-to-last layer.

Comment: @PtitXav yes, maybe we need two steps. step1, collect all penultimate nodes; step2, get one leaf from each node in step1.

Comment: Hi @JimMischel I want to collect the combination of the leaf of the next-to-last layer. In this tree, the next-of-last nodes are `B`, `A`, and `G`. The leaf nodes: `B`:['E', 'F']; `A`:['C']; `G`: ['H', 'I', 'J', 'K']. I want to collect the combination by get one element from ['E', 'F'], ['C'], ['H', 'I', 'J', 'K']

Comment: @Ausrada404 I see. The use of the word penultimate here just confuses the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursion to build the leaf levels, and then apply `itertools.product` to produce the combinations:

```
import itertools
def leaves(tree):
  for x, y in itertools.groupby(tree.children, key=lambda x:not x.children):
     if x:
        yield [i.name for i in y]
     else:
        for i in y:
           yield from leaves(i)

combos = [*itertools.product(*leaves(a))]
```

Output:

```
[('E', 'C', 'H'), ('E', 'C', 'I'), ('E', 'C', 'J'), ('E', 'C', 'K'), ('F', 'C', 'H'), ('F', 'C', 'I'), ('F', 'C', 'J'), ('F', 'C', 'K')]
```